# Can/do C compilers optimize out adress-of in inline functions?

Tags: c, micro-optimization

Let's say I have following code:

```
int f() {
  int foo = 0;
  int bar = 0;

  foo++;
  bar++;

  // many more repeated operations in actual code
  foo++;
  bar++;

  return foo+bar;
}
```

Abstracting repeated code into a separate functions, we get

```
static void change_locals(int *foo_p, int *bar_p) {
  *foo_p++;
  *bar_p++;
}

int f() {
  int foo = 0;
  int bar = 0;

  change_locals(&foo, &bar);
  change_locals(&foo, &bar);

  return foo+bar;
}
```

I'd expect the compiler to inline the `change_locals` function, and optimize things like `*(&foo)++` in the resulting code to `foo++`.

If I remember correctly, taking address of a local variable usually prevents some optimizations (e.g. it can't be stored in registers), but does this apply when no pointer arithmetic is done on the address and it doesn't escape from the function? With a larger `change_locals`, would it make a difference if it was declared `inline` (`__inline` in MSVC)?

I am particularly interested in behavior of GCC and MSVC compilers.

Comment: Your best bet is to try and inspect the emitted assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inline` (and all its cousins `_inline`, `__inline`...) are ignored by gcc.  It might inline anything it decides is an advantage, except at lower optimization levels.

The code procedure by gcc -O3 for x86 is:

```
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl f
        .type   f, @function
f:
        pushl   %ebp
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        popl    %ebp
        ret
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.4 20100630 (Red Hat 4.4.4-10)"
```

It returns zero because *ptr++ doesn't do what you think.  Correcting the increments to:

```
    (*foo_p)++;
    (*bar_p)++;
```

results in

```
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl f
        .type   f, @function
f:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    $4, %eax
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        popl    %ebp
        ret
```

So it directly returns 4.  Not only did it inline them, but it optimized the calculations away.

Vc++ from vs 2005 provides similar code, but it also created unreachable code for `change_locals()`.  I used the command line

```
/O2 /FD /EHsc /MD /FA /c /TP
```

Answer (score 2):

> If I remember correctly, taking
>   address of a local variable usually
>   prevents some optimizations (e.g. it
>   can't be stored in registers), but
>   does this apply when no pointer
>   arithmetic is done on the address and
>   it doesn't escape from the function?

The general answer is that if the compiler can ensure that no one else will change a value behind its back, it can safely be placed in a register.

Think of this as though the compiler first performs inlining, then transforms all those `*&foo` (which results from the inlining) to simply `foo` before deciding if they should be placed in registers on in memory on the stack.

> With a larger change_locals, would it
>   make a difference if it was declared
>   inline (__inline in MSVC)?

Again, generally speaking, whether or not a compiler decides to inline something is done using heuristics. If you explicitly specify that you want something to be inlines, the compiler will probably weight this into its decision process.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested gcc 4.5, MSC and IntelC using this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change_locals(int *foo_p, int *bar_p) {
  (*foo_p)++;
  (*bar_p)++;
}

int main() {
  int foo = printf("");
  int bar = printf("");

  change_locals(&foo, &bar);
  change_locals(&foo, &bar);

  printf( "%i\n", foo+bar );
}
```

And all of them did inline/optimize the foo+bar value, but also did
generate the code for change_locals() (but didn't use it).

Unfortunately, there's still no guarantee that they'd do the same for
any kind of such a "local function".

gcc:

```
__Z13change_localsPiS_:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    incl    (%edx)
    incl    (%eax)
    leave
    ret

_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $28, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    movl    %eax, %ebx
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    leal    4(%ebx,%eax), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $LC1, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addl    $28, %esp
    popl    %ebx
    leave
    ret
```